# What is a connectivity request?

Tags: networking, 18.04

I am trying to diagnose a network problem and noticed that my computer is communicating with an IP address that I'd like to understand.  First, all apps on the desktop were closed so the only thing I have open is my terminal window which is doing nothing but running wireshark.

The computer continuously is communicating with Google at 35.224.99.156 and it says connectivity-check.unbuntu.com.  But a whois on the ip shows Google as the owner.

On a side note:  My router keeps pinging my computer over and over again.  Is that normal?

Comment: `sudo lsof -i` will show you all your connections. There's a lot of activity going on in the background, so "the only thing I have open is my terminal window" isn't quite correct. See `ps -eflwww`. Your "router pings me" is NOT normal and should be fixed on the router.

Comment: There's a setting in your router that sounds something like "Disable ping response on WAN" that should be turned on.

Comment: when I close my browser and type lsof -i nothing shows up.  With browser open I see what it is connected to.   Not sure what I'm getting out of the ps as it is showing a lot of processes running but that doesn't mean they are all connected to the internet.

Comment: as for disabling ping response on WAN,  That wouldn't be causing the router to send pings to my computer.  I've honestly never seen a router do this before so not sure what would even make that happen.

Comment: as for disabling ping response on WAN,  That wouldn't be causing the router to send pings to my computer.  I've honestly never seen a router do this before so not sure what would even make that happen.